# My php header() function is not working

Tags: php, urls, headers, endpoints

//
Edit: I figured it out. Hours and hours of banging my head against a wall and it turns out all this needed was one simple line:

```
ob_clean();
```

Somewhere in some included file there's probably one line of whitespace that is screwing things up. ob_clean() will work for now. Thanks for the effort everyone who helped!
//

Working on a function that displays a random image from a custom endpoint. I have the custom endpoint set up, and am able to retrieve the url of the images. Here is some sample code:

```
$banner = "image/url/from/server/root";

if( !is_readable($banner)) {
                wp_die( "File is not readable: $banner" );
            }

// echo $banner;

$image    = file_get_contents( $banner );

header( 'content-type: image/jpg' );
header( "content-length: " . strlen( $image ) );

echo $image;
```

For some reason, this code is showing a blank image, not the image from the url. I have confirmed multiple times that the url is working by uncommenting echo $banner. I am seeing a url which I am assuming means the is_readable check is passed. I am a real noob when it comes to this stuff. The only thing I can think of is the header() function is somehow breaking my url?

Comment: do you have [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: Yea it's set to true

Comment: Using [`is_readable`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) you need to specify existing filename, even path exist ( without filename ) this function will always return true.

Comment: @Jevuska I'm sorry, can you elaborate on that? The filename is included in the URL I pass to it. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: seems to be suggesting using a `file_exists` check before `is_readable`? you could also add an `if (strlen($image) === 0)` check before outputting the headers to make sure you have data.

Comment: I'm not sure about `content-type: image/jpg` take a look this https://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=4586, you could try `content-type: image/jpeg`

Comment: I just needed ob_clean() guys. I'm going to go cry now. So many hours

Comment: +1 just for that workaround, have always had to track down the damn whitespace and never thought to do that.

Comment: @majick thanks! It's a temporary solution until I can find the whitespace, I've read it's best practice to clean the code up rather than relying on ob_clean().

Comment: for sure, still i'm all for temporary solutions when they can help you get to the next step in solving something. also, worth noting whitespace after a closing `?>` at the end of a file is the most common culprit for this.

Comment: If you've solved your problem either post an answer and accept it, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Hours and hours of banging my head against a wall and it turns out all this needed was one simple line:

```
ob_clean();
```

Somewhere in some included file there's probably one line of whitespace that is screwing things up. ob_clean() will work for now. Thanks for the effort everyone who helped!